# How to disable the Black option of auto replacing single quotes for double-quotes in Vim

Tags: vim

I'm using [Black](https://github.com/python/black) code formatter for Python3 in Vim like this (installing the plugin with `vim-plug`):

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

Plug 'ambv/black'

call plug#end()

autocmd BufWritePre *.py execute ':Black'
```

This is working as expected, **but I want to disable the Black option of auto replacing single quotes for double-quotes. Is there a way to do that in the `.vimrc` file?**

Note that Black CLI has the following option to do that: `-S, --skip-string-normalization`.

Please keep in mind I'm a beginner in Vim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use the plugin in question, but it looks as if you can achieve the result you want with the following line in your `.vimrc`:

```
let g:black_skip_string_normalization = 1
```